# Trouble Configuring DataProtection Key Management Options in ASP.NET Core 3: "An error occurred while reading the key ring"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kubernetes, data-protection

I'm trying to [use this sample code](https://joonasw.net/view/using-azure-key-vault-and-azure-storage-for-asp-net-core-data-protection-keys) because my kubernetes replica set of Kestrel servers needs to share the session cookie database. I have a basic ASP.NET Core 3 C# web-app.

I used the Azure cli to

1. Create a storage account
2. Create a blob storage container inside that account
3. Recorded the storage account key
4. I could not find the command to create an empty blob and discovered that if I upload one, they are created on demand
5. I created a key vault and was able to fetch a key vault key.

Here is my code inside the ConfigureServices function:

```
WriteLine("Begin ConfigureServices");
var redisName = GetEnvironmentVariable(name: "REDIS_DNS_NAME", "my-redis-master.default.svc.cluster.local");
var redisPassword = GetEnvironmentVariable(name: "REDIS_PASSWORD", "xxxxxxxxxxx");

var settings = Configuration.GetSection("DataProtection").Get<DataProtectionSettings>();

WriteLine($"settings={settings}");
WriteLine($"AddDataProtection");

services.AddDataProtection() ;

// Replicates PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage
// There is no overload to give it the func it ultimately uses
// We need to do that so that we can get refreshed tokens when needed
services.Configure<KeyManagementOptions>(options =>
{  // https://joonasw.net/view/using-azure-key-vault-and-azure-storage-for-asp-net-core-data-protection-keys
    options.XmlRepository = new AzureBlobXmlRepository(() =>
    {
        WriteLine($"new AzureBlobXmlRepository: settings={settings}");
        // This func is called every time before getting the blob and before modifying the blob
        // Get access token for Storage
        // User / managed identity needs Blob Data Contributor on the Storage Account (container was not enough)
        string accessToken = _tokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://storage.azure.com/", tenantId: settings.AadTenantId)
            .GetAwaiter()
            .GetResult();
        WriteLine("Create blob reference with token: new Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Auth.TokenCredential(accessToken)");
        var tokenCredential = new Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Auth.TokenCredential(accessToken);
        WriteLine("new Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials(tokenCredential)");
        var storageCredentials = new Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials(tokenCredential);
        var uris = $"https://{settings.StorageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net/{settings.StorageKeyContainerName}/{settings.StorageKeyBlobName}";
        WriteLine($"new Uil({uris})");
        var uri = new Uri(uris);
        WriteLine($"uri={uri}");
        // Note this func is expected to return a new instance on each call
        WriteLine($"new Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob(uri, storageCredentials);");
        var blob = new Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob(uri, storageCredentials);
        return blob;
    });
});
```

After looking at the log (see below), it looks I'm dying on that call `_tokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync(...)` because I'm not supplying a connection string but I don't see a connection string parameter for that function where I might specify a connection string. I'm not sure what this would be a connection string to...

I see I can get a connection string with

```
az.cmd storage account show-connection-string  -g $AZ_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME -n $AZ_STORAGE_ACCOUNT
```

Is this what it wants? Where do I add it to the code?

I can also use this to create a connection string:

```
az.cmd storage account show-connection-string --blob-endpoint $AZ_ASPNETCORE_BLOB_NAME -g $AZ_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME -n $AZ_STORAGE_ACCOUNT
```

Here are the results from the pod log:

```
settings=AadTenantId=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx StorageAccountName=acctstoragexxxxx  StorageKeyContainerName=dataprotection StorageKeyBlobName=keys.xml KeyVaultKeyId=https://keyvaultname.vault.azure.net/keys/keyvaultkey/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
AddDataProtection
new AzureBlobXmlRepository: settings=AadTenantId=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx StorageAccountName=acctstoragexxxxx  StorageKeyContainerName=dataprotection StorageKeyBlobName=keys.xml KeyVaultKeyId=https://keyvaultname.vault.azure.net/keys/keyvaultkey/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
[41m[30mfail[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider[48]
      An error occurred while reading the key ring.
Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProviderException: Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://storage.azure.com/, Authority: https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx. Exception Message: Tried the following 3 methods to get an access token, but none of them worked.
Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://storage.azure.com/, Authority: https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Managed Service Identity. Access token could not be acquired. Received a non-retryable error. MSI ResponseCode: BadRequest, Response: {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Identity not found"}
Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://storage.azure.com/, Authority: https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Visual Studio. Access token could not be acquired. Environment variable LOCALAPPDATA not set.
Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://storage.azure.com/, Authority: https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Azure CLI. Access token could not be acquired. 

   at Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProvider.GetAuthResultAsyncImpl(String resource, String authority, Boolean forceRefresh, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync(String resource, String tenantId, Boolean forceRefresh, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at WebApp_OpenIDConnect_DotNet.Startup.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<ConfigureServices>b__5() in /src/Client/Startup.cs:line 120
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AzureStorage.AzureBlobXmlRepository.CreateFreshBlobRef()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AzureStorage.AzureBlobXmlRepository.GetAllElements()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager.GetAllKeys()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider.CreateCacheableKeyRingCore(DateTimeOffset now, IKey keyJustAdded)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider.Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.Internal.ICacheableKeyRingProvider.GetCacheableKeyRing(DateTimeOffset now)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider.GetCurrentKeyRingCore(DateTime utcNow, Boolean forceRefresh)
[40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Internal.DataProtectionHostedService[0]
      Key ring failed to load during application startup.
Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProviderException: Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://storage.azure.com/, Authority: https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx. Exception Message: Tried the following 3 methods to get an access token, but none of them worked.
Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://storage.azure.com/, Authority: https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Managed Service Identity. Access token could not be acquired. Received a non-retryable error. MSI ResponseCode: BadRequest, Response: {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Identity not found"}
Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://storage.azure.com/, Authority: https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Visual Studio. Access token could not be acquired. Environment variable LOCALAPPDATA not set.
Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://storage.azure.com/, Authority: https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Azure CLI. Access token could not be acquired. 

   at Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProvider.GetAuthResultAsyncImpl(String resource, String authority, Boolean forceRefresh, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync(String resource, String tenantId, Boolean forceRefresh, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at WebApp_OpenIDConnect_DotNet.Startup.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<ConfigureServices>b__5() in /src/Client/Startup.cs:line 120
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AzureStorage.AzureBlobXmlRepository.CreateFreshBlobRef()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AzureStorage.AzureBlobXmlRepository.GetAllElements()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager.GetAllKeys()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider.CreateCacheableKeyRingCore(DateTimeOffset now, IKey keyJustAdded)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider.Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.Internal.ICacheableKeyRingProvider.GetCacheableKeyRing(DateTimeOffset now)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider.GetCurrentKeyRingCore(DateTime utcNow, Boolean forceRefresh)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider.GetCurrentKeyRing()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Internal.DataProtectionHostedService.StartAsync(CancellationToken token)
```

**Mon Nov 02 2020 Evening Update**

[I've been studying this article by Bac Hoang](https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2020/01/exploring-azureservicetokenprovider-class-with-azure-key-vault/) where I see some error messages that are similar to mine. It looks like one needs to go to the portal.azure.com to adjust some settings for access policies for VMs. But I'm not using VMs directly because I'm using kubernetes.

I confirmed I can access the vault (this works):

```
az.cmd login --service-principal --username $env:SP_APPID --password $env:SP_SECRET --tenant $env:SP_TENANT
az account get-access-token --resource https://vault.azure.net
```

But I believe this is not necessary because I'm not calling ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault (yet) because Jonas says this is optional.

Maybe Jonas is wrong and I need to call ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault?

Jonas's code won't compile for me:

```
var kvClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(_tokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));

services.AddDataProtection()
.ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault(kvClient, settings.KeyVaultKeyId);
```

`ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault` only has two overloads and neither accepts a keyVaultClient...

Can someone show me some sample code to call ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault? It wants a keyIdentifier (is this a key vault key?) and a keyResolver and a keyResolver wants Azure.core.TokenCredential and there are over a dozen descendents of this abstract TokenCredential class! Which do I want? I cannot find any examples anywhere!

Thanks

Siegfried

Comment: Updated official documentation [Configure ASP.NET Core Data Protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview).